# Django rank search in Postgres not matching

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a Tutorial model with name 'building'.

Here is search.

```
tutorial_search = Tutorial.objects.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(SearchVector('name'), query)
).filter(rank__gte=0.0001).order_by('-rank')
```

This query finds my model

```
query = 'bui:*'
```

But this one doesnt

```
query = 'buildi:*'
```

I cant figure out what is causing it. Is it english accent?
Seems like simple search.

**EDIT:**

I tried pure SQL queries in postgres, and I get the same result.
This works:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('building') @@ to_tsquery('(build:*)');
```

Returns True

But this one:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('building') @@ to_tsquery('(buildi:*)');
```

Returns False

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you asked for the motivations of the behavior of your queries.

You can test the lexems generated from your words in your queries as below:

```
SELECT ts_lexize('english_stem', 'building');
 ts_lexize 
-----------
 {build}

SELECT ts_lexize('english_stem', 'build');
 ts_lexize 
-----------
 {build}

SELECT ts_lexize('english_stem', 'buildi');
 ts_lexize 
-----------
 {buildi}
```

As you can see the lexems generated by 'building' and 'build' are the same ('build') and 'buildi' generate a different 'buildi'.

This is because the first two work and the third does not.

More info in the [Testing and Debugging Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-debugging.html) documentation.